# What is the fail safe way to query Date Period in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my tables I use timestamp field to fix when the user created the record and other field to see when he/she updated the record last time.

When I then create a query to show the admin the records created or updated from the first day of the month to the last day, if I use two `TDateTimePick` component to get those dates, I do not get all the records because the component inserts the current time, and it conflicts my timestamp.

In order to get out of this I use now a text field where I save the dates as numbers like YYYYMMDDHHMMSS and then I query `Left(numered_date, 8) >= $begin_date and Left(numered_date, 8) <= $end_date`.

But my client is complaining that some data is missing on the reports.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better (fail save) way to check those dates?

I have a problem that I am from Brazil and here the date is like DD/MM/YYYY. And for that I have to sometimes create a new Text Field with the date formatted to this.

Comment: Why don't you store your dates in datetime fields? That's much easier to work with then as strings.

Comment: can you show your `INSERT INTO` statement? Do you use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Why is this tagged `Firebird`?

Comment: I removed both the `delphi` and `firebird` tags, because this question has nothing to do with either of them. Please use only the tags relevant to your question (in this case, `mysql` and `sql`). Tags are meant to identify your question as being about specific topics, so that they can be noticed by people familiar with those topics and so they can be searched using those topics. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, I use it this method in both MySQL and Firebird databases. The insertion is automatic by the Delphi TIBTable or TZTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use datetime fields. And also, take a look at

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

- I'm also brazilian, by the way
- Mail me (in portuguese (if you prefer)) if you have other doubts

[edited from here]
I'm talking too much. I forgot to mention a few things. Take a look at the following command,

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1234567890, '%d / %m / %Y, %k : %i');
```

Ok. One more secret for you (about Delphi):
(long time I don't use Delphi, but maybe it helps you)
You should use "AdoQuery" objects, instead of "ADO" ones.
This way you'll be able to use your own selects. And also, you can create views (certainly it'll be helpful in any language!). You can create a view in witch you get a formatted date (just the way you want).
Views saved me a lot of time since I had to do tons of DAOs (data access objects) to list forums, topics, posts etc. Then I made some views for them. And just one DAO for querying from my views.
*Guys, sorry for my English BTW

Comment: @EASI I've completed my answer (I wonder if people are automatically warned about answer updates).

Comment: It's very good your answer, and I have upvote you before that, but we can do that only once for each answer. I use ZeosLib in Delphi, but my views I made in MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin. I will check if there we can change the output date format. Thanks!